# What am I doing wrong trying to center this div? (its a little off)

Tags: jquery

I am trying to center a div horizontally to a marker as you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/rKejG/8/, however it's a little more to the right than it should be.

This is my code

```
$("#infobox").css({
    marginLeft: (parseInt($("#content").width(), 10) / 2) - (parseInt($("#infobox").width(), 10) / 2) + 'px'
});
```

Then I realized that I should probably add the halves of `content` and `infobox` and put them in a negative margin, but that made it a whole lot worse:

```
$("#infobox").css({
    marginLeft: '-' + (parseInt($("#content").width(), 10) / 2) + (parseInt($("#infobox").width(), 10) / 2) + 'px'
});
```

`Result: margin-left: -16110.5px`

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: You are not closing your div tags correctly for one. Run your HTML through the W3C validator and see what you come up with.

Comment: Oops, Okay small mistake there. Fixed that.

Comment: Why do you set the padding twice on .infobox?

Comment: Ach :D, as I was playing with the styles and javascript I lost track of some things :)

Comment: However that shouldnt be the issue regarding the positioning.

Comment: Do you want the arrow to be directly in the center of your infobox div?

Comment: I think it's because of the **infobox** padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cleaned up the html and set the `marker` class to `position: relative`.  That seems to have resolved your issue.  I also out the extra padding, and removed the additional margin in the marker class.  I think I did a couple other changes in the css, you'll have to compare the original.  There was quite a bit to clean up.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/rKejG/17/)

UPDATE:
Now that I go back, the position relative to the parent of an absolutely positioned element is good practice, but not required and is not what fixed this.  The extra padding in the infobox class and static margin in the content class, as well as the html not being nested fixed the issue.

[UPDATE][UPDATE]

Based on what you have, I think you need a wrapper with css `width:100%; padding-top:45%; position:relative` and then set your child divs with `margin: 0 auto` as shown in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/rKejG/22/  You can set the top padding to the container to be whatever you want of course.  However I may be missing the point.  Do you want the text centered above the marker regardless of where the marker is located?

Comment: Thanks, however why did you remove the `width: 32px` from the `#content`? When I put that back in, I get this result - and still not centered: http://i.imgur.com/gnIIkNA.png

Comment: You know, when I applied your code to the fiddle, I didn't see the marker image and didn't know what it was.  I have fixed it now and see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I changed your script around a little bit, but it produces the correct result.

http://jsfiddle.net/rKejG/15/

JS Code:

```
   //for vertical center position
   var top = +$("#content").offset().top + +$("#content").height();
   $("#infobox").css("top", top);


   //for horizontal center position
   var left = +$("#content").offset().left - +$("#infobox").width()/2;
   $("#infobox").css("left", left);
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="content" class="marker"></div>
  <div id="infobox" class="infobox">BEER PALACE Restaurant & Pub</div>
```

I couldn't figure out why you were using margins to align your "infobox" div, so I just used absolute positioning. This should work no matter where the "content" div is positioned on the page.

I also couldn't figure out why you were appending the "infobox" div to your "content" div, and if this is supposed to show the "infobox" after an event, (an assumption I made based on your naming), you probably don't want it to be a child, but rather a sibling. Of course let me know if this assumption is wrong, I can always modify the fiddle.

Comment: That doesn't look like my fiddle, here's what it looks like in Chrome for me http://imgur.com/lWALYc5. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I changed it to display above the marker, because I'm planning on making the infowindow expand "up" to show more info when you hover. The point is, in your example - it's still sticking out to the left a little more, just like my original version.